# Schematic to breadboard circuit

Tags: breadboard

I have just bought my Arduino Uno rev3. I am really interested in Arduino.
For my first project I have to buy a breadboard and actually I did.I saw the schematic circuit in the book " beginning arduino programming " and I tried to make it .But I have a serious problem here . I am really interested in learning " breadboarding " . I mean I want to know how I can assemble a breadboard circuit from it's schematic and vice versa.
Are there any books , sites or resources that can help me by this?

Answer (score 1):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/) has schematic, breadboard, and PCB views, and allows you to switch between them freely in order to place components and make changes to the circuit.